# Discord timed key system that adds and removes roles (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to add a system to my key generating system I want it to be able to generate a key once claimed will give you a role and remove that role after a certain amount of time almost like a subscription but I have no idea how to do that

```
#Create Key
@bot.slash_command(name = "createkey", description = "Creates a key")
@commands.has_role("Litteral Owner")
async def createkey(ctx, key):
   with open("keys.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(key + "\n")
   await ctx.respond("Key Created", ephemeral = True)

@createkey.error
async def createkeyerror(ctx, error):
 if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRole):
    await ctx.respond("You can't use this command because you don't have the Owner role!", ephemeral = True)
 else:
     raise error

#Claim Key
@bot.slash_command(name = "claim", description = "Claims a key")
async def claim(ctx, key, member : discord.Member):
 keys = open('keys.txt', 'r')
 read_content = keys.read()
 if f"{key}" in read_content:
    await ctx.respond(f"key Valid \nKey: {key}", ephemeral = True)
    member = member or ctx.message.author
    guilds = ctx.guild
    role = discord.utils.get(guilds.roles, name="Buyer")
    await member.add_roles(role)
    with open("keys.txt", "r") as f:
     lines = f.readlines()

    with open("keys.txt", "w") as f:
     for line in lines:
        if line.strip("\n") != key:
            f.write(line)
 else:
    await ctx.respond("Invalid Key", ephemeral = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html). You could store the time a user was given a role/key and run the "key checking task" every few minutes (or however long you want your intervals to be) and then if their time as that role/key expires; you can remove it from them. For storing the role/time data, perhaps look at something like [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) so you can store data in a different format.